# Integrating twisted into existing pyqt GUI application

Tags: python, pyqt4, twisted

I am trying to add twisted to my already existing app. According to [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qt4reactor/1.6) and other sources, I should import qt4reactor. When I try:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
from twisted.application import reactors
reactors.installReactor('pyqt4')
```

(I also tried:)

```
from twisted.internet import qt4reactor
```

I get twisted.application.reactors.NoSuchReactor: 'pyqt4'. I can download and install qt4reactor directly, but then I can't install it after instantiating QApplication?

Also, since I am adding on twisted, the documentation states that I should use reactor.runReturn() instead of reactor.run().

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
reactor.listenTCP(8001, tcpFactory())
reactor.runReturn()
```

When I try this, I get AttributeError: 'SelectReactor' object has no attribute 'runReturn'. Is this because I am unable to install qt4reactor after instantiating QApplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now qt4reactor is separate from Twisted and located [here](https://github.com/ghtdak/qtreactor)

So you need to install it first, then try:

```
from twisted.application import reactors
reactors.installReactor('pyqt4')
```

or

```
from qtreactor import pyqt4reactor
pyqt4reactor.install()
```

Comment: I get 'ImportError: cannot import name qtreactor'

Comment: @camerausb oh, I meant that first you need to install a python package (with pip, etc..) from the link above, as twisted website now points there https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/QTReactor

Comment: The 2nd option works, but I am unable to pass in app explicitly. Throws error 'TypeError: win32install() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: @camerausb alright, seems that now it accepts no arguments (previous had both options)